# How to get all XML revisions for a Wikipedia article?

Tags: wikipedia

I am trying to get all the details of revisions made to a given Wikipedia article in the form of XML files. I am, however, not able to get it completely. For example [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export) provides an XML containing only 1000 edits.

The details to get all the revisions are given [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export).

I used curl to get it, however, I could not get what I desire. Has anybody used this method? Or is there any other method to get an XML or a set of XMLs containing all the revisions of an article?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all Wikipedia page's revision history by using [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvprop=parsetree&titles=Tiger%20snake&rvlimit=500
```

**rvlimit** is `50` for normal users, `500` for registered and `5000` for bots. To get all revisions you need to create a loop by using **rvcontinue** value from the previous response.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. But I still haven't been able to get the XML. When I follow the address given by you, I do not get the XML. Can you pls guide more? For example, I want an XML having ALL the revisions of 'United States' article. Thanks

Comment: Can you pls help me how and where to execute the above query as well as how to use 'rvcontinue' to get all the revisions of an article?

Comment: @xerox this is a web request. For example, you can use [`rvlimit=2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvprop=parsetree&titles=Tiger%20snake&rvlimit=2) to get only the first 2 revisions in XML format. If you need the next 2, you have to use the `rvcontinue` from the last response and etc. In my case it will be https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvprop=parsetree&titles=Tiger%20snake&rvlimit=2&rvcontinue=20161226225453|756802289